# Best embedded Linux mid range processor with video capability

Tags: processor, linux, embedded-systems

I want to get up and running fast with an embedded Linux processor eval board that is cheap but capable of processing video.

**edit:** By processing video, I mean it should be able to take a 720p stream from a camera, insert an overlay on it for display and save the data without overlay to sd card.

I used at91sam9 before so something newer but equivalent with good video capability might be good.

Also, easy instructions to build using yocto would be helpful.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "processing video"?  Decoding MPEG-1, encoding 1080p x264, and adding overlays to a broadcast stream could all be considered "processing video", but have very different hardware requirements.

Comment: True.  Will edit now

Comment: How much budget do you have?

Comment: Requirements must be met to meet requirements, video, accelerometer and another sensor.  And application as described above.  So price doesn't matter but no point paying more than necessary.